# Parse a PHP generated (from .xsd template) XML file

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, parsing, xsd

I am trying to parse an XML **(in Objective-C)** file that is generated in PHP from a template, as seen below.

I have tried parsing this with a standard XML parser, but does not seem to load.

What would be the best way to parse this PHP XML generated file? Maybe a 3rd party library?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:pbu="http://www.something.com/something.xsd" xmlns="http://www.something.com/something.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.something.com/something.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="app">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bannerImg" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="category" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="25">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="image" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="40">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="thumbUrl" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="sampleUrl" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="imageUrl" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="infoUrl" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="license" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                                    <xs:element name="licenseUrl" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="icon" type="xs:anyURI" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="unlock_product_id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="unlock_product_id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You claim you have a valid XML file.  Then any tool (Internet Explorer) should be able to load it; doesn't matter how you got it.  Are you sure it valid?

Comment: Well, thats the thing, it doesn't load like a normal feed in **Safari**.

Comment: Based on weak evidence, it sounds like your file isn't legal.  You're being pretty obscure about the actual complaint though.  I'd check your PHP generator; it may not work as well as claimed.

Comment: Your XML is well-formed, though I can't claim whether or not the contents are correct.  Can you perhaps tell us about what errors or problems you are encountering?  Any XML parser should be able to work with this file.  "It does not seem to load" isn't a good enough error message for us to actually provide useful help.

Comment: Off topic, but JSON is really nice. =)

Answer (score 0):

I had to parse an equal structure a few months ago. I didn't try with the xml parser. I did it with [TBXML](https://github.com/codebots-ltd/TBXML). It's great if you know the structure of the XML file. And it's really well documented. ;-)

Sandro Meier